# Pandas DF - Group by Sender, Calculate "Frequency" of Emails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have 15,000+ emails in my inbox and I am trying to clean it up. I currently have a script that has collected all my email data, but now I am trying to find out which domains are emailing me the most and at what rate. I currently have a pandas dataframe that is a series of emails and the date I received it like this (this is the list/dictionary form pre-dataframe)

```
[{'epoch': '1613345709000',
 'date': '2021-02-14 23:35:09',
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': '1613320070000',
 'date': '2021-02-14 16:27:50',
 'domain': 'email.vans.com',
 'From': 'vansinfo@email.vans.com'}]
```

What I am essentially trying to do next is calculate the frequency that each of these senders are sending me on a monthly basis.

I have this all in my jupyter notebook so eventually want visualize the data.

The struggle I am running into is the frequency part when I do a groupby. I am having a hard time figuring out if I need a Lambda to convert this data, or if there is some additional group section other than sum() or mean() to get this data.

So an example output I am looking for after a group by is like,

```
from : store-news@amazon.com, frequency : 35
```

OR

```
domain : amazon.com, frequency : 35
```

Frequency being the average I get per month.

So far I have done basic things like

So far I have mainy just done:

```
newdata = email_df.groupby(by="domain").sum()

newdata = email_df.groupby(by="domain").average()
```

but it complains about lack of int, so not even sure how to work with dates here.

Comment: Can you show some pandas/python code you have tried already?

Comment: added some examples, but really sure where even to start with pandas on this.

Comment: `email_df.groupby(by="domain").count()` should work. something like `email_df.groupby(by="domain").count()['epoch']` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. I created some random data and printed the output for you.

You need to get the Year-Month for the date, then groupby domain & year_month, while counting the # epochs. Since you want just to print the domain, year-month, and counts per month, you can write the output to a dictionary, then print them.

```
dcount = df.groupby(['domain','Month'])['epoch'].count().to_dict()
```

This will give you a dictionary that can then be printed.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
test_data = [{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,10,22,22,22) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,10,22,22,22),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,11,12,12,12) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,11,12,12,12),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,14,10,10,10) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,14,10,10,10),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,20,18,30,20) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,20,18,30,20),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,27,16,40,50) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,27,16,40,50),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,2,11,13,37,29) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,2,11,13,37,29),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,2,12,13,35,16) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,2,12,13,35,16),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': '1613345709000',
 'date': '2021-02-14 23:35:09',
 'domain': 'amazon.com',
 'From': 'store-news@amazon.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,12,15,30,20) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,12,15,30,20),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'email.vans.com',
 'From': 'vansinfo@email.vans.com'},
{'epoch': str(int((datetime(2021,1,20,18,30,20) - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())*1000),
 'date': datetime.strftime(datetime(2021,1,20,18,30,20),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
 'domain': 'email.vans.com',
 'From': 'vansinfo@email.vans.com'},
{'epoch': '1613320070000',
 'date': '2021-02-14 16:27:50',
 'domain': 'email.vans.com',
 'From': 'vansinfo@email.vans.com'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
dcount = df.groupby(['domain','Month'])['epoch'].count().to_dict()
for k,v in dcount.items():
    print (f'domain : {k[0]},\tYear-Month : {k[1]},\tfrequency : {v}')
```

The output of this will be:

Input dataframe:

```
            epoch                 date          domain                     From
0   1610317342000  2021-01-10 22:22:22      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
1   1610367132000  2021-01-11 12:12:12      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
2   1610619010000  2021-01-14 10:10:10      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
3   1611167420000  2021-01-20 18:30:20      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
4   1611765650000  2021-01-27 16:40:50      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
5   1613050649000  2021-02-11 13:37:29      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
6   1613136916000  2021-02-12 13:35:16      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
7   1613345709000  2021-02-14 23:35:09      amazon.com    store-news@amazon.com
8   1610465420000  2021-01-12 15:30:20  email.vans.com  vansinfo@email.vans.com
9   1611167420000  2021-01-20 18:30:20  email.vans.com  vansinfo@email.vans.com
10  1613320070000  2021-02-14 16:27:50  email.vans.com  vansinfo@email.vans.com
```

The output print is:

```
domain : amazon.com,        Year-Month : 2021-01,   frequency : 5
domain : amazon.com,        Year-Month : 2021-02,   frequency : 3
domain : email.vans.com,    Year-Month : 2021-01,   frequency : 2
domain : email.vans.com,    Year-Month : 2021-02,   frequency : 1
```

If you want to get the count of all the emails you received in a month, that's easy to find out as well. You just need to get a sum of all the frequencies for the month. Then you can use that to get a percentage of emails you got for each domain. There are a lot of things you can do once you have the data.

Comment: @Mallachar, does this meet your requirements?

Comment: works great, thank you. (Sorry was in Texas during the power outage)